# Permission denied when installing npm modules in OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to install `node-g.raphael`, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Bender-03:htdocs alfred$ sudo npm install node-g.raphael --save
Password:

> contextify@0.1.15 install 
  /Users/alfred/Sites/twistedgeo/htdocs/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
  '/Users/alfred/Sites/twistedgeo/htdocs/node_modules/contextify/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
  "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
  "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd 
  /Users/alfred/Sites/twistedgeo/htdocs/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v8.8.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 
  (node_modules/contextify):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 
  install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ node-g.raphael@0.0.9
added 2 packages and updated 1 package in 6.556s
```

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45521080/138863), but it doesn't solve my problem, still getting the same error.

Let me know if there's anything I can add to help in solving this.

Answer (score 458, accepted):

Saw this from [Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) and it helped, maybe you could give it a shot as well.

### Option 1: Change the permission to npm's default directory

1. Find the path to npm's directory:

   `npm config get prefix`

For many systems, this will be `/usr/local`.

**WARNING**: If the displayed path is just `/usr`, switch to *Option 2* or you will mess up your permissions.

2. Change the owner of npm's directories to the name of the current user (your username):

   `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

This changes the permissions of the sub-folders used by npm and some other tools (`lib/node_modules`, `bin`, and `share`).

### Option 2: Change npm's default directory to another directory

There are times when you do not want to change ownership of the default directory that npm uses (i.e. `/usr`) as this could cause some problems, for example if you are sharing the system with other users.

Instead, you can configure npm to use a different directory altogether. In our case, this will be a hidden directory in our home folder.

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
3. Open or create a `~/.profile` file and add this line:

   `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables:

   `source ~/.profile`

**Test**: Download a package globally without using `sudo`.

```
`npm install node-g.raphael --save`
```

Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify `~/.profile`):

```
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

### Option 3: Use a package manager that takes care of this for you.

If you're doing a fresh install of Node on Mac OS, you can avoid this problem altogether by using the `Homebrew` package manager. `Homebrew` sets things up out of the box with the correct permissions.

`brew install node`

Comment: Thanks @Antz. I had to do the same thing to my local node_modules, probably because I had attempted installing node-g.raphael with sudo. d'Oh! Though I now have another issue related to xcode... But that'll be for another question.

Comment: This answer helped me big time. Thank you for the well crafted and understandable answer. one note, if you use the Fish shell and you are using option 1 then you'll need to remove the `$` in the command so it will read as follows: `sudo chown -R (whoami) (npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`  again thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I tried doing OPTION 2 steps. On MacOS Catalina v10 the default shell is ZSH which uses ~/.zprofile instead of ~/.profile. That is why with configuration above did not work at first on terminal but when used BASH shell it worked.
You can find detailed description here:
https://superuser.com/a/187673

Comment: Does granting NPM all of the same permissions as your primary user account grant scripts executed by NPM permission to read/write to all directories the primary user can r/w? And make network requests? Since NPM scripts are rarely studied in full by downloading user, doesn't it make more sense from a security standpoint to create a separate user for NPM and grant r/w permission to that user only on the global NPM directories +  local development directories?

Comment: Instead of messing with `/usr/local`, I just moved `npm`'s global directory to `/Users/Shared/.npm-global` and changed my shell's profile accordingly. Everything under `/Users/Shared` should be available to all users, so it works and avoids using `sudo`. The older stuff in `/usr/local` keeps working as long as it's in `PATH`, but one can uninstall everything (except for `npm`) before changing the `prefix` parameter and reinstall everything in the new location.

Comment: I tried option 2. source `~/.profile` is saying no such file or directory and trying to re-run the instll npm command I am getting `npm: command not found`

Comment: @nickornotto ensure your npm file is in `/usr/local/bin/npm`, if you still don't find it there, you might need to reinstall node.js (https://nodejs.org/) again.

Comment: How can discard those changes? lol

Comment: @JORGEGARNICA what changes are you talking about? Be specific.

Comment: @antzshrek I mean, I'm stucked trying to revert all changes to keep the default directory and everything regarding node and .nvm.

Comment: I had some kind of directory issues with option 2 as given. But I just navigated to the npm path manually and then ran the respective `chown` commands, which worked.

Comment: I was trying to install node and nvm on macOS Montery and when trying to install a package (npm install -g ...) I kept getting a 'EACCES' error. Option one solved the permission issue for me.

Comment: @ckoerner 'EACCES' error obviously looks like a permission thing

Answer (score 9):

I use:

1. `npm config get prefix`
2. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`
3. `sudo npm install`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing your file permissions and risking confusion within your system (what I have done and may live to regret at a later date), may I suggest the following that I found after the fact.

[Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Answer (score 0):

```
Brew uninstall node 
Brew install node
```

create a link if there is an error and if link doesn't work do the following
Simply run these four commands:

```
  sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/include/node
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/bin
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share
    sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/lib/dtrace
```

Finally, run the overwrite command:

brew link --overwrite node

Answer (score -7):

To get access on Mac/Linux, simply use this command

```
sudo npm install -g {package_name}
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: If you want to install any dependency globally inside your Mac or linux.You have to use sudo or configure manually in settings for all packages

Comment: [You don't need `sudo` to install packages globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712034/6282576), and you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score -16):

Issue fixed for me by running the below command.

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Was able to install angular.

Then try running ng -v to confirm.