# getting error while adding android platform to ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, native

When I add the android platform for ionic, its getting an error like `missing write permission`

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall
>   access npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] { npm ERR!   stack:
>   "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'", npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!
>   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR! } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The
>   operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely
>   you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current
>   user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions
>   issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and
>   its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again
>   as root/Administrator.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: run comment as super user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this

> https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/

solution 1)

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

solution 2)

```
sudo npm install -g
```

solution 3)

[Permission denied when installing npm modules in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252451/permission-denied-when-installing-npm-modules-in-osx)

Comment: sudo ionic cordova run android try this

Comment: or close and reopen terminal and try.

Answer (score 0):

You miss rights to write in the folder
Try to execute this cmd :

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a fresh install of Node on Mac OS, you can avoid this problem altogether by using the Homebrew package manager. Homebrew sets things up out of the box with the correct permissions.

brew install node

My issue solved by using this command

Answer (score 0):

you are getting permission problem, that's why u are getting problem

it can resolved by giving permission

```
sudo var chmod 777 /directory/
```