# I have a problem when I install angular on terminal macOs

Tags: angular, macos, npm, terminal

I would like to install angular but when I type the command these error messages appear. Could someone help me? Thank you in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDxRm.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied when installing npm modules in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252451/permission-denied-when-installing-npm-modules-in-osx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules-react - please check if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sudo`

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Using sudo with npm can be a security issue as it hands over elevated privileges to the install scripts of all dependencies. Answers that depend on it should probably include some disclosure of that risk. See https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

Answer (score 0):

Access is denied since the node_modules folder is owned by root. Changing permissions of this folder should resolve the error.

First check who owns this directory and then change permissions accordingly.

Cmd to check owner:

```
ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Then, change user using the below cmd:

```
sudo chown -R [owner]:[owner] /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

**EDIT:**

Using sudo to install the package will also resolve the error but changing permissions of the Directory will help in the long run, so you don't run into the same error while installing a different package.