# Why can't I install anything with Node on my Mac OS Catalina

Tags: node.js, macos, command-line, terminal, macos-catalina

I've needed to install a number of things with node but ever since I updated my system to Catalina I just get errors that I'm assuming are due to the new security measures on Mac.

The last thing I tried to install was this command:

```
npm install -g gulp gulp-cli browser-sync
```

I got this error

```
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jessiematias/.npm/_logs/2020-03-31T15_45_46_951Z-debug.log
```

How can I ensure I don't get these errors anymore whenever I try to install something on the command line? It's saying to try running the commmand again as root/Administrator. How do I do that?

Comment: Seems that you have no permission to write to `/usr/local/lib/`. How do you install node and npm?

Comment: I downloaded Node manually from a browser. Before updating to Catalina

Comment: Hello please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47252840/13171371
Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, that helped. Thanks!