# Getting error "EACCES: permission denied" when i install cypress

Tags: cypress

When i try to install cypress using this commnad:

```
sudo npm install cypress
```

or

```
sudo npm install -g cypress
```

It is giving me this error:

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/humac/node_modules/cypress/cypress.zip'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied when installing npm module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520853/permission-denied-when-installing-npm-module)

Comment: i tried but now getting this error ; Cypress cannot write to the cache directory due to file permissions
----------

Failed to access /Users/humac/Library/Caches/Cypress:

EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/humac/Library/Caches/Cypress'
----------

Platform: darwin (17.7.0)

Answer (score 35):

Workaround: sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root cypress

Answer (score 21):

In my case cypress had trouble accessing `/root/.cache/Cypress` upon `npm install`:

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.cache/Cypress'
```

I found a [relevant issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1281) and ended up setting a custom cache dir:

```
export CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/app/.cache
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

After clearing my Cypress cache folder with `cypress clear cache` I ran into this issue as well.

This is what I did:

1. `sudo rm -rf` the Cypress folder in your .cache directory
2. For me I also deleted the Cypress folder in node_modules
3. Cleaned cache with `npm cache clean --force`
4. Installed Cypress with `npm install cypress --save-dev`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had issues running Cypress on Mac

```
An unexpected error occurred while verifying the Cypress executable.  

----------

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/me/Library/Caches/Cypress/9.7.0/binary_state.json'

----------

Platform: darwin-x64 (22.2.0)
Cypress Version: 9.7.0
```

The easiest think to do is to locate the folder within **Finder** app, and for both "Cypress" and "9.7.0" folder and adjust the permissions for "everyone" and "staff"  to "Read & Write".

*Note: You must click on the lock icon and use your mac admin/system password to change the permissions.*

[image: changing permissions]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `yarn` package manager or downgrading `npm` to version 7.
For me it worked correctly.

I'm using **Jenkins** in an **alpine linux** container with **node 16**.

```
    stage('Prepare-build') {
    steps {
        sh 'node --version'
        sh 'npm --version'
        sh 'ls -p'
        sh 'git config --global --add safe.directory "*"'
        sh 'yarn install'
    }
}
```

The error I was getting is the following:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/project/app/project-web-manager/node_modules/cypress
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /tmp/postinstall-716e113e.sh
npm ERR! Cypress cannot write to the cache directory due to file permissions
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See discussion and possible solutions at
npm ERR! https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1281
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ----------
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed to access /root/.cache/Cypress:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.cache/Cypress'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ----------
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Platform: linux-x64 (Alpine Linux - 3.16.1)
npm ERR! Cypress Version: 10.6.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-18T17_09_27_887Z-debug-0.log
```

In my same case export the environment variable cypress cache folder did not work as expected, the error was even made mentioned above.

```
export CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER="/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/project/app/.cache"
```