# Cypress file permissions on Mac issue

Tags: cypress

**Error: EACCES: permission denied, open ‘/Users/palisaski/Library/Application Support/Cypress/cy/production/projects/CyZavrsniProjekat-3356f9979cb849d912b38aef8a005fde/bundles/cypress/integration/homePageTests.js’**

On Mac, tried to run some scripts, but keep getting this message. I am using sudo command to run cypress.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress requires root access, you need to install it accordingly and make sure you have the proper permissions. See [#1281](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1281)

[Getting error "EACCES: permission denied" when i install cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151786/getting-error-eacces-permission-denied-when-i-install-cypress)